# Using OAuth2 in dropbox API

Tags: java, api, oauth

I'm using the Dropbox API in my Java desktop application. I implemented the authorization process with the redirect to localhost to get the access token.
Everything works perfect so far but if I later try to connect to Dropbox to share some files, an exception is thrown:

```
com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadRequest: {"error": "v1_retired"}
```

So I think the retrieved access token is only an OAuth1 token. In the API bundle I found a OAuth1Upgrader to convert the token. But that seems a bit too complex.
So my question: Is there a way to get an OAuth2 token immediately during the authorization process?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox deprecated their v1 API on Sept 28th (see [this post](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/)). All API calls from that day forward to v1 endpoints return a 400 error with the message:

> {“error”: “v1_retired”}

as happened here.

They published a migration guide [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide). Reading through it, there's a mapping between the v1 endpoint you're probably using and the v2 endpoint you should be able to use to get the OAuth2 token:

> /1/oauth2/authorize:/oauth2/authorize

Comment: But how can I make this mapping for API calls? I'm using classes like DbxRequestConfig, DbxClient, DbxEntry etc.

Comment: Do you have their SDK for their v2 API? Here's the GitHub repo for it: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java.

Comment: Yes I know this repository but I read something about Android and Google App Engine etc. so I thought that this API is for Android apps only. Was this wrong? Is the API built for Android and Desktop applications alike?

Comment: It should work for both, since it's written in Java. I searched through their repositories and there isn't a separate SDK for Android.

Comment: Ok, then I will try it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Comment: Here is also an alternative SDK for Java and Dropbox which you might consider useful. It also works for other providers like OneDrive and they keep the API consistent. https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage;platformId=Java;serviceIds=Dropbox